# Unable to hide navbar back button (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I"m currently trying to hide the Back button on the navbar, and I've tried using both `.navigationBarHidden(true)` and `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` but it doesn't actually hide the button. Here is the code I'm using for both views.

View Two

```
struct ThirdOnboardingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
        ZStack{
            Color("SmokyBlack").ignoresSafeArea()   
            Image(imageName)
                 .resizable()
                 .scaledToFit()
                 .padding(.top, 80)
        }// main zstack ends
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        }
    }
}
```

View One

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
        ZStack{
            Color("SmokyBlack").ignoresSafeArea()                        
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                 .padding(.top, 80)
             Spacer()
                    
             NavigationLink(destination: ThirdOnboardingView(),
                label: {Text("Navigate")})
            }// parent vstack
        }// main zstack ends
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        }
    }
```

If there are any missing brackets in the code, its just an error I made while typing it out, the code builds and runs just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be only one `NavigationView` in your root view (first view in hierarchy), so

```
struct ThirdOnboardingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{       // remove this one !!
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: That particular view gets linked to another view, I just haven't included that code because its the same code

Comment: It does not matter - `NavigationView` must be only one in one navigation stack, otherwise you will have a lot of issues, not only that in topic. All subsequent NavigationLink works (adds) at that root `NavigationView`.

Comment: I see, one moment, I will test it out